# How can I see what is using all my bandwidth on cisco IOS?

Tags: nat, cisco-ios

I have a cisco router performing NAT for my local network.  Download bandwidth is stagnant at 2MB/s and I'm not sure which host is responsible for this and what exactly it's connecting to.  How can I find this?  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your external interface use:

```
interface {interface} {interface_number}
ip route-cache flow
bandwidth <kbps>
exit
```

Then use the command below to get some data about usage:

```
show ip cache flow
```